# Reprojection between custom LCC and other EPSG using rasterio is wrong

Tags: coordinate-system, rasterio

I try to reproject a GeoTIFF that has this proj4 info:

```
'+proj=lcc +lat_1=49.5 +lat_0=49.5 +lon_0=10.5 +k_0=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=km +no_defs=True'
```

(and its crs info)

```
CRS.from_wkt('PROJCS["unnamed",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_1SP"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",49.5],PARAMETER["central_meridian",10.5],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",49.5],UNIT["kilometre",1000,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9036"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]')
```

If I try to reproject it to EPSG:2100 with the following code from rasterio's documentation, it succeeds, however when importing the reprojected raster to Arcmap, I see that the coordinates are wrong. It is way far more North and East than it should be (around 3500 km and 2500 km). What am I doing wrong? Should I add false northing/easting?

```
dst_crs = 'EPSG:2100'

with rio.open("2021_2030_1.tif") as src:
    transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
        src.crs, dst_crs, src.width, src.height, *src.bounds)
    kwargs = src.meta.copy()
    kwargs.update({
        'crs': dst_crs,
        'transform': transform,
        'width': width,
        'height': height
    })
    

    with rio.open("2021_2030_1_gg.tif", 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
        for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
            reproject(
                source=rio.band(src, i),
                destination=rio.band(dst, i),
                src_transform=src.transform,
                src_crs=src.crs,
                dst_transform=transform,
                dst_crs=dst_crs,
                resampling=Resampling.nearest)
```

Comment: I'm guessing an issue with the input km units. Maybe try unprojecting it to lat/lon first?

Comment: Not sure how to get it done properly. You mean reprojecting to EPSG 4326 (WGS84)?

Comment: I just tried, and it is misplaced as well. An area at lon 20, lat 40 is at around 72, 52 degrees. If it helps, the dataset is from CORDEX, covering the whole Europe.